# linq - Substitute Non-Generic Lambda Expression for Generic Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a this line of code:

```
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntityType, bool>>(body, param);
```

where TEntityType is a generic parm.

However, I don't have generic parm available. I do have:

```
Type _EntityType;
```

What is the non-generic syntax for Expression.Lambda is this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's an overload for `Expression.Lambda` that takes the type of the expression body, so you just need to create the type dynamically before calling that overload.

```
type lambdaType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(_EntityType, typeof(bool));

var predicate = Expression.Lambda(lambdaType, body, param);
```